# How to return a value from void in android

Tags: android-timepicker

Hello I m new to android development I m developing an app which requires to get the hour and minute from timePicker so I did like this to get it:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TimePicker timePicker;
 int hour, changedHour;
 int minute, changedMinute;
TextView tv, tv1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
    setCurrentTime();
    timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new OnTimeChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker arg0, int hourOfDay,
                int minuteOf) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Time set!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            changedHour = hourOfDay;
            changedMinute = minuteOf;

            tv.setText("Hour of Day is " + changedHour + " and Minute is "
                    + changedMinute);
        }

    });
    tv1.setText("Hour of Day is " + changedHour + " and Minute is "
                    + changedMinute);
}

public void setCurrentTime() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    timePicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
    timePicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);

}`
```

The problem is here

```
changedHour = hourOfDay;
            changedMinute = minuteOf;

            tv.setText("Hour of Day is " + changedHour + " and Minute is "
                    + changedMinute);
```

I got the changed time and I set it like hour would be in `hourOfDay = changedHour` and same for minute now outside the method when I m trying to use the variables the problem is its set to 0 HERE

```
tv1.setText("Hour of Day is " + changedHour + " and Minute is "
            + changedMinute);
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never actually assign to the `changedHour` or `changedMinute` variables before you print them using `tv1.setText`, since it's very likely that `onTimeChanged` hasn't ever fired by that point. For this reason, they'll have their default values of 0, since they haven't been assigned anything else yet.

Anyway, you can't return values out of a `void` function. By definition, `void` is a lack of a type.

How to fix this depends on how exactly you want the code to work. The path of least resistance would be to set `changedHour` and `changedMinute` from within `setCurrentTime`, e.g.

```
public void setCurrentTime() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // NEW CODE
    changedHour = hour;
    changedMinute = minute;
    // END NEW CODE

    timePicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
    timePicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);

}
```

You *could* return the hour and minute through some other mechanism (return a struct or use out parameters), but given that you update `changedHour/Minute` in your `onTImeChanged` callback, it probably wouldn't fit well with the existing flow.

On a re-read though, this could all just be because you're using the wrong variable in `tv1.setText`. You assign to the class variables `hour` and `minute` in `setCurrentTime`, so you could just print those rather than `changedHour` and `changedMinute`, e.g.

```
tv1.setText("Hour of Day is " + hour + " and Minute is "
                + minute);
```

Comment: Testing it hope that your method works and thanks for the good explanation!

Comment: Nope what your code is doing that it is setting the current time to changedHour I want the app to set the changed time to changedHour and by the way the changedHour used in void method setCurrentTime is working fine and not in the onChangedTimeListener o.O